# Search for letters in a word

Tags: android, android-searchmanager

I'm using a SearchManager in my app to search for words in SQLite database. It works fine, but I would like to search for letters in a word. For example, if you search for `cpur` it would show the words that cointain those letters (`computer`). Is there a way to customize the search manager to work like that?

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to answer this if you had given more informations, but lets assume you select words like this:

```
select words from text where word='target'
```

you can get words that looks like it as well this way:

```
select word from text where word like '%target%';
```

meaning that on either side of target, there can be any number of characters from the string.
Hope this helps and is what you needed.

Comment: I'm using the Android sample project SearchableDictionary http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Database/SearchableDictionary.htm

Answer (score 0):

or, if You don´t want to use sqlite commands, this should work also after You have get the String from Your table:

```
       boolean contains = false;

      if(YourWord.contains(YourNeededString)){
               contains =   true;
     else{
               contains =   false;
          }
```